# unable to set state in react for provided situation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am building a ecommerce web app with react and i am unable to set state profileOptionsLayer when i click on the highlighted listitem both the logs are displayed on the console but component dosent rerender and state "profileOptionsLayer" is not updated either ,i am unable to locate the reason need help!

```
ALL imports .....

const TemporaryDrawer = ({
  profileDrawerlayer,
  setprofileDrawerlayer,
  setuserDetails,
  userDetails,
}) => {
  const [profileOptionsLayer, setprofileOptionsLayer] = useState();
  console.log(profileOptionsLayer);
  return (
    <>
      <Drawer
        anchor={"right"}
        open={profileDrawerlayer}
        onClose={() => {
          setprofileDrawerlayer(false);
        }}
      >
        <Box
          sx={{ width: 250, background: "lightblue", height: "100%" }}
          role="presentation"
          onClick={() => {
            setprofileDrawerlayer(false);
          }}
          onKeyDown={() => {
            setprofileDrawerlayer(false);
          }}
        >
          <List>
////////////////////////////////////// Below ///////////////////////////////////////////////
            <ListItem disablePadding>
              <ListItemButton
                onClick={() => {

                  console.log("dsadsa");
                  setprofileOptionsLayer("View"); <= unable to set this state
                  console.log(profileOptionsLayer);
                  console.log("dsadsa");
                  }}
              >
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <VisibilityIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={"View Profile"} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
/////////////////////////////////////// UP /////////////////////////////////////////
             <ListItem
              disablePadding
              onClick={() => {
                localStorage.removeItem("userId");
                setuserDetails("");
              }}
            >
              <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <LogoutIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={"Logout"} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>

          </List>
          <Divider />
        </Box>
      </Drawer>
      {profileOptionsLayer &&<ProfileOptions {...{ userDetails }} />}
    </>
  );
};
export default TemporaryDrawer;
```

Comment: `useState("");` and you should read about useState and what happens when you try to console.log() it

Comment: Ive used empty useState() many times and it works fine , Value of state remains the same on console.log inside onClick function , nothing changes

Comment: if you try to console.log() a state variable you will always log the previous state atleast in the way you are trying to log it

Comment: But why the state isnt updating ? It is always the default one

Comment: try using a useEffect and console.log profileOptionsLayer and see if it changes

Comment: I think i got the answer, it is because of the props , i am setting a prop to false which is unmounting the entire current component. Btw Thanks for your time